# Removing Azure IoT Hub device twin tags

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I can add new tags to Azure IoT Hub Device Twin with below step

await _registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, patch, twin.ETag);

But how do you remove a tag that is added previously?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a previously added property by setting its value to **null**. You can find an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#back-end-operations

Comment: Thanks for the link @Dominic. That did it: Here I am sharing my C# code:

var patch =@"{tags: {custom: { '" + property + "' : null }}}";